# macOS: How to identify the Built-in audio output device? Can I rely on the UID(BuiltInSpeakerDevice)?

Tags: macos, mac, audio, speakers

I am trying to figure out which device is the built-in output device on my Mac using [switchaudio-osx](https://github.com/deweller/switchaudio-osx)? when I use `exec -a -f json` in the list I can see

```
{"name": "MacBook Pro Speakers", "type": "output", "id": "366", "uid": "BuiltInSpeakerDevice"}
```

But my concern is that is it safe to use the uid `BuiltInSpeakerDevice`? will it be the same on all Mac devices and OS versions?